# Retrieving double the specified limit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

I'm having this weird issue where I set a limit (and offset) on the client side (JS), send it to a Rails controller via ajax, and even though the params say the limit is what I expect (14), it spits out double (28). There's a 'view more' button which than paginates another set of tracks and ups the offset, again supposed to be 14, says its 14, but spits out an additional 28. I log some puts statements, and the output is what I'd expect (limit 14, offset increments by 14 each time it paginates). Any ideas on why I'm getting double the limit I'm specifying? Here's some codez:

Here are the JS functions that are relevent:

```
 function queue(params, method) {
    var req;
    params = params || {};
    params = _.extend(params, {
      limit: 14,
      order: _order
    });
    method = method || 'html';
    req = {
      params: params,
      method: method
    };

    fetch(req);
  }

  /**
   * Hits our filter_tracks controller action
   * @private
   */
  function fetch(req){
    self.spin(true);
    if (mm.isMobile) {
      mm.spin(true);
    }

    if(_fetchingAjax) _fetchingAjax.abort();
    _fetchingAjax = $.ajax({
      url: '/filter_tracks',
      data: req.params,
      success: function (data) {
        $resultsTarg[req.method](data);
        buildTracks();
        mm.facade.trigger('bypass');
        self.spin(false);
        if (mm.isMobile) {
          mm.spin(false);
        }
        if (mm.isMobile && !req.params.offset) {
          self.view(false);
        }
        if (!req.params.offset) _.defer(count);
      }
    }).always(function(){
      _fetchingAjax = null;
    });
  }

  /**
   * Tracks must be built (instantiated) every time the partial is rerendered or
   * becomes extended with the 'view more' button
   * @private
   */
  function buildTracks() {
    var tracks = $('.track-item', $resultsTarg);
    // if tracks already exist, remove them [MAKE ME BETTER]
    if (_tracks.length) {
      _tracks.forEach(function (track) {
        track.destroy();
      });
      _tracks = [];
    }
    // recreate tracks
    tracks.each(function (i, track) {
      _tracks.push(mm.Track($(track)));
    });
  }
```

It goes here in my tracks controller:

```
def filter_tracks

    params[:limit] ||= 50
    params[:offset] ||= 0
    params[:order] ||= 'rank DESC'

    puts "/" * 150
    puts params[:limit]
    puts params[:offset]
    puts "/" * 150


    # heavy rotation filter flag
    heavy_rotation ||= (params[:order] == 'rank DESC')


    @result_offset = params[:offset]
    @tracks = Track.ready.with_artist

    params[:order] = "tracks.#{params[:order]}"

    if params[:order]
      order = params[:order]
      order.match(/artist.*/){|m|
        params[:order] = params[:order].sub /tracks\./, ''
      }
      order.match(/title.*/){|m|
        params[:order] = params[:order].sub /tracks.(title)(.*)/i, 'LOWER(\1)\2'
      }
    end


    @tracks = parse_params(params[:q], @tracks)

    @tracks = @tracks.offset(params[:offset])

    @result_count = @tracks.count

    @tracks = @tracks.order(params[:order], 'tracks.updated_at DESC').limit(params[:limit])

    # restructure heavy rotation results
    if heavy_rotation

      puts "*" * 150
      puts params[:limit]
      puts params[:offset]
      puts "*" * 150

      three_weeks_ago = Time.now - 21.days

      # sub-query top results
      tracks_top_results = @tracks.where(
        "tracks.updated_at >= :top", 
        top: three_weeks_ago
      )

      # sub-query remaining
      tracks_remaining_results = @tracks.where(
        "tracks.updated_at < :remaining", 
        remaining: three_weeks_ago
      )

      @tracks = tracks_top_results + tracks_remaining_results
      @tracks.shuffle!


    end

    render partial: "shared/results"
  end
```

> EDIT:

Here's the logs:

```
2015-03-16T17:06:27.637654+00:00 app[web.2]: Started GET "/browse?_ajax=1" for 198.0.42.137 at 2015-03-16 17:06:27 +0000
2015-03-16T17:06:27.748603+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_results.html.erb (0.9ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:27.659777+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by TracksController#index as */*
2015-03-16T17:06:27.659818+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"_ajax"=>"1"}
2015-03-16T17:06:27.745758+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_sorter.html.erb (0.7ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:27.753180+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_table.html.erb (6.5ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:27.753270+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered tracks/index.html.erb (40.1ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:27.753674+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 78.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:27.769464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/browse?_ajax=1" host=staging-marmosetmusic.herokuapp.com request_id=846db817-4654-43ab-8f99-7994b8a18950 fwd="198.0.42.137" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=136ms status=304 bytes=378
2015-03-16T17:06:27.960153+00:00 app[web.2]: Started GET "/moods.json?bucket=story" for 198.0.42.137 at 2015-03-16 17:06:27 +0000
2015-03-16T17:06:28.188416+00:00 app[web.2]: Started GET "/filter_tracks?limit=14&order=rank+DESC" for 198.0.42.137 at 2015-03-16 17:06:28 +0000
2015-03-16T17:06:28.210975+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by TracksController#filter_tracks as */*
2015-03-16T17:06:28.211023+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"limit"=>"14", "order"=>"rank DESC"}
2015-03-16T17:06:28.222862+00:00 app[web.2]: //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
2015-03-16T17:06:28.222866+00:00 app[web.2]: 14
2015-03-16T17:06:28.222868+00:00 app[web.2]: 0
2015-03-16T17:06:28.222870+00:00 app[web.2]: //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
2015-03-16T17:06:28.318029+00:00 app[web.2]: ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
2015-03-16T17:06:28.318037+00:00 app[web.2]: 14
2015-03-16T17:06:28.318039+00:00 app[web.2]: 0
2015-03-16T17:06:28.318041+00:00 app[web.2]: ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
2015-03-16T17:06:28.348873+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by TracksController#moods as JSON
2015-03-16T17:06:28.348884+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"bucket"=>"story"}
2015-03-16T17:06:28.478141+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/moods.json?bucket=story" host=staging-marmosetmusic.herokuapp.com request_id=b68356eb-7b2f-4341-ba30-29d6d3e4ff5d fwd="198.0.42.137" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=527ms status=304 bytes=378
2015-03-16T17:06:28.463840+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 200 OK in 115ms (ActiveRecord: 8.0ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.710111+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (115.9ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.463520+00:00 app[web.2]: Read fragment views/staging-marmosetmusic.herokuapp.com/moods.json (1.4ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.593527+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (10.0ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.714491+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.7ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.720260+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.7ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.725627+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.5ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.717344+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.6ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.722971+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.5ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.728223+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.4ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.734289+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.1ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.741642+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.3ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.748142+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.9ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.758640+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.9ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.758645+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.2ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.730928+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.5ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.737758+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.1ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.744971+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.0ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.752438+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (4.0ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.765492+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.9ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.773917+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.0ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.780813+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.4ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.788779+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.1ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.796253+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.1ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.762271+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.7ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.770673+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (4.9ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.778036+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.8ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.785552+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (4.0ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.792803+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (3.7ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.799688+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_track_item.html.erb (2.9ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.799694+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered shared/_results.html.erb (219.2ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.799893+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 200 OK in 589ms (Views: 222.2ms | ActiveRecord: 170.6ms)
2015-03-16T17:06:28.834891+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/filter_tracks?limit=14&order=rank+DESC" host=staging-marmosetmusic.herokuapp.com request_id=ebb74235-f5a5-4501-ab52-7857ef93db5d fwd="198.0.42.137" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=649ms status=200 bytes=5515
```

Comment: What does the resulting actual DB query look like?

Comment: @Albin I've added the logs to the question above. Thanks.